# How to add custom information to a Play Store crash report?

Tags: java, android, google-play, crash-reports

I am trying to debug an error reported on "Crashes and ANRs" on the Play Store, which I suspect is triggered by specific user input in a field (which I am allowed to collect per my app's privacy policy).

I wonder if I could somehow include that field's content in my reports, so I could figure out what sort of input is causing the (quite rare, but annoying) crashes. Tried to search the documentation and beyond, but could not find such a possibility.

I've done that easily in the past with services like Sentry, but this being a free/open-source app (which I maintain with limited time and resources), I'd wish to keep using Play Store. Is that possible? If not, any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: If the error is caused by en Exception/Throwable catch it and crate a new RuntimeException with the field details as message and the original exception attached.

Comment: Oh, indeed, wrapping the exception and using the message, that's a great idea! (and like all the great ones, obvious in hindsight). Please feel free to write as a response, I'll be happy to choose it as correct, Robert. Thank you!